# How can access contact identifier from callKit

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I start callkit call with this code:

```
private func startCallKitCall(call: Call, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()){

    let handle              = CXHandle(type: .phoneNumber, value: call.handle)
    let startCallAction     = CXStartCallAction(call: call.uuid, handle: handle)
    startCallAction.isVideo = call.hasVideo
    startCallAction.contactIdentifier = call.uuid.uuidString
    let transaction         = CXTransaction(action: startCallAction)

    requestCallKitTransaction(transaction, completionHandler: { success in
        completion(success)
    })

}
```

in contactIdentifier I set the user UUID, then in provider, update the caller remote name:

```
public func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXStartCallAction) {

    let update = CXCallUpdate()
    update.remoteHandle = action.handle
    update.hasVideo = action.isVideo
    update.localizedCallerName = "TestCallName"
    self.provider!.reportCall(with: action.callUUID, updated: update)

    action.fulfill()

}
```

I use "TestCallName" as localizedCallerName, now on recent call of my phone, I see a row named "TestCallName", If I click it, I call this method on appdelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {


    if (userActivity.activityType == "INStartAudioCallIntent"){

        guard let interaction = userActivity.interaction else {
            return false
        }

        var personHandle: INPersonHandle?

        if let startVideoCallIntent = interaction.intent as? INStartVideoCallIntent {
            personHandle = startVideoCallIntent.contacts?[0].personHandle
        } else if let startAudioCallIntent = interaction.intent as? INStartAudioCallIntent {
            personHandle = startAudioCallIntent.contacts?[0].personHandle
            print(startAudioCallIntent.contacts?[0])
        }
        print(personHandle!.value)

    } else if (userActivity.activityType == "INStartVideoCallIntent"){

    } else {
        print("called userActivity: \(userActivity.activityType), but not yet supported.")
    }

    return true
}
```

but the output I obtain is:

```
Optional(<INPerson: 0x1742a5280> {
contactIdentifier = "<null>";
customIdentifier = "<null>";
displayName = "<null>";
image = "<null>";
nameComponents = "<null>";
personHandle = "<INPersonHandle: 0x17402f0c0> {\n    label = \"<null>\";\n    type = PhoneNumber;\n    value = \"TestCallName\";\n}";
relationship = "<null>";
siriMatches = "<null>";
})
 Optional("TestCallName")
```

i see only the name "TestCallName", but contact identifier is "null", how can I fix this? I see there is also a field name "customIdentifier", can I use this?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `contactIdentifier` is the ID of the contact in contacts app. The one you set into `startCallAction.contactIdentifier` means nothing. To call a user you need to use either phone or email or at least name.

Comment: Alexander - I have a number of questions about using CallKit - not directly related to this chain. Is there an okay way to get in contact with you?

Comment: Ok, but I almost forgot how it works =) You can try.